# Error using DGESV in Matlab mex

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, lapack

I'm trying to solve a linear system with DGESV in a mex file.
When I have a 2x2 system, the mex file works fine and no errors occurred, but when the system is larger than 2, MATLAB System Error dialog box apperas and says that matlab has encountered an internal problem and needs to be closed.
Im using matlab r2016a on 64-bit windows 10 and intel composer XE 2013

The compile line is:

```
mex -lmwlapack *.F
```

The code is as follows:

```
     #include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway subroutine
      subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwPointer mxGetM

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
      mwPointer pr_A, pr_B, pr_C

C     Array information:

      mwPointer sizea 
      real*8 , allocatable :: A(:,:)
     +        ,B(:,:),C(:,:)

C     Get the size of the input array.
      sizea = mxGetM(prhs(1))

        allocate(A(sizea,sizea),B(sizea,1))
        allocate(C(sizea,1))

C     Create Fortran array from the input argument.
      pr_A = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      pr_B = mxGetPr(prhs(2))

      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr_A,A,sizea**2)
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr_B,B,sizea)

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizea, 1, 0)
      pr_C = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

C     Call the computational routine.
      Call SolveLS(A,B,C,sizea)

      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(C,pr_C,sizea)

      return
      end

C     Computational routine
      subroutine SolveLS(A,B,C,sizea)

      integer*4 :: sizea,pivot(sizea),info
      real*8 :: A(sizea,sizea),B(sizea,1), C(sizea,1)

      call DGESV(sizea, 1,A,sizea,pivot,B,sizea,info)
      C=B
      return
      end subroutine SolveLS
```

Comment: Never ever use "doesn't work" or "won't work". Describe what is happening. Any error messages? Which exactly? Wrong results? Which operating system you use?

Comment: Don't put any Thanks or signatures into your questions. It is not expected here. Describe your problem in a concise way.

Answer (score 1):

A system error like this normally indicates that you've corrupted the memory with a bad memory allocation.  I notice you are using the standard Fortran allocate function instead of mxMalloc which allows MATLAB to handle the memory allocation and deallocation.  Note that mxMalloc'ed memory is automatically destroyed at the end of the MEX function call, but you can use mxFree to free it up.

Information on mxMalloc can be found in [the Matlab help files](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxmalloc.html)

Comment: Is memory allocation this critical that even a simple 3x3 system cannot be solved?

Comment: It depends on what the memory allocation overwrites!  That's the thing about dynamic memory allocation - one slip and it can produce errors that only show up occasionally, or behaviour that is inconsistent from run to run.  Just the other day I had strange behaviour from some MEX code which I traced down to having not manually initialised dynamically allocated memory before using it.  (I had assumed it was allocated as zeros, which it wasn't).  Matlab provides mxMalloc so that it can better handle allocations - it works similarly to allocate, so worth a shot!

Comment: I'd like to test that, but im not an expert and dont know how to do that, even after i read the matlab help, so can i have a hint or a small code to understand how to do that?

Comment: I don't program in Fortran as a general rule (C would be my language of choice), but what you need to do is set the pointers you declared for A, B and C to the result of mxMalloc.  The argument to mxMalloc needs to be the size of the space in bytes, so you'll need to multiply your array size by the number of bytes each element requires for storage.  The only bit I'm unsure about is how Fortran works with two dimensional arrays in such situations!  The syntax would be something like: `B=mxMalloc(sizeof(real8)*sizea)`.  You'll need some Fortran expert to help with the 2D array, A, I'm afraid!

Comment: @Ali If you are using Fortran already why don't you directly call LAPACK ?

Comment: @ percusse i dont know what you mean