# How to use mxCalloc in fortran mex-file

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I have to use mxCalloc function instead of regular allocation in mex file to avoid matlab from crashing while using dgesv.
I've tried many ways but none of them worked.
Here's one of the samples

```
 #include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway subroutine
      subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwPointer mxGetM

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
      mwPointer pr_A, pr_B

C     Array information:

      mwPointer sizea,mxCalloc
      real*8 :: A,B
      character*120 :: line

C     Get the size of the input array.
      sizea = mxGetM(prhs(1))

      A=mxCalloc(sizea*sizea,8)
      B=mxCalloc(sizea*sizea,8)

C     Create Fortran array from the input argument.
      pr_A = mxGetPr(prhs(1))

      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr_A,A,sizea**2)

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizea, sizea, 0)
      pr_B = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

      write(line,*), sizea
      call mexPrintf(line) 
      B=A

      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(B,pr_B,sizea*sizea)

      return
      end
```

when i run this code, i get the following result

> A =  [0.9575 , 0.1576 ; 0.9649 , 0.9706]
>
> test(A) = [0.9575 , 0 ; 0.9649 , 0]

but if i change the line 
`call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(B,pr_B,sizea*sizea)` 
to

`call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(A,pr_B,sizea*sizea)`, 
the results are correct

the variable sizea is equal to 2 which is correct, but i cant access any member of A, say A(1,1), and heres the error i encounter:

> error #6410: This name has not been declared as an array or a
>   function.   [A]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I have no experience with Mex, so please take the following code as such...)

This is some continuation of the answers by @ftiaronsem and a previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509572/error-using-dgesv-in-matlab-mex) by Dave. By looking at this [tutorial](http://home.versatel.nl/tngoudsw/mexf90.html), it seems OK to use Fortran allocatable arrays in the `mexfunction()`. But, the purpose of the OP is to use `mxCalloc()` rather than allocatable arrays for memory management.

According to the online manual of Matlab, `mxCalloc()` seems to return the address of the allocated memory as `mwpointer` (which is just an alias of `integer*8` on 64-bit machines, according to the header file [`fintrf.h`](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwio6rq-g_DPAhXElJQKHXr4C5gQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftware.intel.com%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2F7d%2Fa0%2Ffintrf.h&usg=AFQjCNHWu0CE3hP9L-jaxAKeC9_HxQ1s2g&sig2=Ryl02_TjlXPIEM23y5VEfQ)). So, we first get the address as

```
mwpointer iA
iA = mxCalloc( sizea * sizea, 8 )
```

(and similarly for `B`). Next, we want to access the memory starting from `iA` as 2-d Fortran array. This can be done by using [c_f_pointer()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fF_005fPOINTER.html) (in F2003). But, since the first argument of this function receives `type(c_ptr)`, we proceed as follows:

```
use iso_c_binding
type(c_ptr) cA
real*8, pointer :: A(:,:)

cA = transfer( iA, cA )                      !! cast integer*8 to c_ptr
call c_f_pointer( cA, A, [ sizea, sizea ] )  !! init an array pointer with c_ptr
```

After this statement, we can use `A` as an ordinary 2-d Fortran array (e.g., we can pass it to LAPACK routines). Including these modifications into the OP's code gives the following. So could you try it and see whether it works or not...?

---

Updated code (ver1):

```
#include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway subroutine
      subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

      use iso_c_binding    !<---

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwsize    mxGetM, sizea          !<--- changed to mwsize (may not be necessary, though)

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
      mwPointer pr_A, pr_B

C     Array information:

      mwPointer mxCalloc

      mwPointer       :: iA, iB           !<---
      type(c_ptr)     :: cA, cB           !<---
      real*8, pointer :: A(:,:), B(:,:)   !<---

      character*120 :: line

C     Get the size of the input array.
      sizea = mxGetM(prhs(1))

      iA = mxCalloc( sizea**2, 8 )   !<---
      iB = mxCalloc( sizea**2, 8 )   !<---

      cA = transfer( iA, cA )        !<---
      cB = transfer( iB, cB )        !<---

      call c_f_pointer( cA, A, [ nsizea, nsizea ] )   !<---
      call c_f_pointer( cB, B, [ nsizea, nsizea ] )   !<---

C     Create Fortran array from the input argument.
      pr_A = mxGetPr(prhs(1))

      call mxCopyPtrToReal8( pr_A, A, sizea**2 )

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizea, sizea, 0)
      pr_B = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

      write(line,*), sizea
      call mexPrintf(line) 
      B = A

      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr( B, pr_B, sizea**2 )

      !! may need to call mxFree( iA ) and mxFree( iB ) manually?
      !! (or Matlab may automatically do it upon exit)

      return
      end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it seems ok

Comment: but i still cant use dgesv, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the code where you use dgesv. It is impossible to tell what might be going wrong without seeing actual code. And I think it would be a good idea to do this in a different question since your original one "How to use mxCalloc in fortran mex-file" seems to have been solved by this answer.

Answer (score 3):

A in the code is declared as a single variable, but size(A,1) is trying to access it as if it was an array. You will have to tell Fortran explicitly that A has the shape of an array. After a quick glance on the rest of the code I assume that A and B are supposed to be 2 dimensional

```
 real*8 :: A(:,:),B(:,:)
```

Now I don't know too much about how mxCalloc works and how it handles the memory allocation and interfacing to Fortran, but it could be that you also need to declare A and B as pointers.

```
real*8, pointer :: A(:,:),B(:,:)
```

Comment: i have used this syntax, there is no error while building the mex file, but matlab crashes if you use the mex file

Comment: Do you know at what line in the fortran file matlab crashes? You could insert print statements into the fortran code, or if those are for whatever reason not displayed in matlab, create files to see where it crashes. Also could you show us the matlab code that is calling this function?

Comment: also try to print (or write) the value of sizea right after the line  sizea = mxGetM(prhs(1)). Does it have the right value?

Comment: there are some changes in the question that i think refrences your comments

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, it does help. However in your last edit you also reverted back to using real*8 :: A,B instead of using real*8 :: A(:,:),B(:,:). Was that on purpose? This is what the error #6410 is complaining about.

Comment: if you use real*8 :: A(:,:),B(:,:), the mex file will compile but wont run

Comment: Yes, but the first step is to get your mex file to compile and then you need to debug why it crashes. In Fortran you do need to declare arrays and their dimensions. I would encourage you to take a look at xtimesy.F (edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/refbook/xtimesy.F']);)  This is pretty much what you are trying to do if x=1. There are two things to pay attention to: First mxCopyPtrToReal8 copies into a 1 dimensional array and second this array is reshaped into a 2 dimensional array in the xtimesy subroutine. I don't know whether you can use mxCopyPtrToReal8 to copy ...

Comment: ... directly into a 2D array. Furthermore I don't know for sure whether you need to statically alloate the arrays as in the xtimesy.F or whether you can use allocate to do that dynamically (although I would wager you probably can). I can only tell you that the errors you have been reporting and the results you got are because you declare A as a single variable but then you use it as an array.

Comment: According to some document of Matlab, mxCalloc() seems to return "mwPointer", so I guess it is basically wrong to assign the function result to real variables (nor real arrays). Btw, is it not sufficient to just allocate A and B as usual Fortran allocatable arrays, copy the contents of Matlab input arrays to them, do necessary stuff with A and B, and copy back the result to output Matlab arrays?

Comment: Something like this: https://svn.ecdf.ed.ac.uk/repo/ph/IGM/matlab/src/fintrf.h (sorry if my guess is totally wrong, I have no experience with Matlab nor Mex)

Comment: my actual problem arises when i want to use DGESV

Comment: i have a code with approximately 2000 lines for solving a boundary value problem, and the code works just fine except the part that solves the equation. i've used mexCallmatlab instead of lapack and that works, but i have to solve system of equations like 800'000 times per itteration, so it's really the matter of speed for me.

Comment: if i use the usual allocation, matlab crashes, and i'm sure that the problem is  memory allocation. there is a example of what i want to do in C:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/8006/1/dgesv.c

Comment: Just to make sure, could you paste your code that fails (crashes) with Fortran allocatable arrays? (by adding the code after your original question as "edit", so that the original question should be kept intact.) Looking at the C code above, it may be possible to use c_f_pointer() + Fortran array pointers, but if allocatable arrays works, it should be much simpler.

Comment: Allocatable arrays works for this case, but as i told you in commnts, i need to use mxcalloc for another code, and i made up a simple code just to understand the way that mxcalloc works

Comment: OK, I now understand the situation... I will try to "translate" the above C code to Fortran using c_f_pointer() etc. Please wait a bit... (possibly one day, because I cannot do it now).